# calculus of variations with double integral textbook?

Tags: reference-request, self-learning, book-recommendation, calculus-of-variations

I am interested to learn about doing calculus of variations with double integrals.

i.e. maximizing a functional 
$$J(f(x,y))=\int_0^1\int_0^1f(x,y)dxdy$$
w.r.t. $f$.

Are there good textbooks on this?

Comment: I believe the correct notation would be $J(f)=\int_0^1\int_0^1f(x,y)dxdy$. After all, the arguments $x$ and $y$ are exhausted within the double integral. In addition, you must specify the degree of regularity of the $f$ function. Is it class $C^1$ or just continuous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know of a book that is entirely devoted to variational cálculus in $R^2$. But I know of a collection of books that contains problems of calculus of variations in $R^2$, $R^3$ and in general in $R^n$. These problems are scattered throughout the chapters of the following books:

- V. Barbu and T. Precupanu. Convexity and optimization in Banach spaces. D. Reidel Publishing Co., Dordrecht, third edition, 1986.
- P. Blanchard and E. Bruning ¨ . Variational methods in mathematical physics. Texts and Monographs in Physics. Springer-Verlag, Berlin, 1992.
- B. Dacorogna. Direct Methods in the Calculus of Variations. Springer-Verlag, Berlin, 1989.
- B. Dacorogna. Introduction to the calculus of variations. Imperial College Press, London, 2004.
- I. Ekeland and R. Temam. Convex Analysis and Variational Problems. North Holland, 1976.
- M. Giaquinta and S. Hildebrandt. Calculus of Variations I. The Lagrangian Formalism. Springer, Berlin, 1996.
- M. Giaquinta and S. Hildebrandt. Calculus of Variations II. The Hamiltonian Formalism. Springer, Berlin, 1996.
- Struwe. Variational Methods. Applications to Nonlinear Partial Differential Equations and Hamiltonian Systems. Springer-Verlag, Berlin, 1990.
- J. L. Troutman. Variational calculus and optimal control. Undergraduate Texts in Mathematics. Springer-Verlag, New York, 1996.

Comment: Wow, thanks. I have never heard of $n$-integrals. Where are these applied? physics?